# Update records dbal innodb silex

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, silex, dbal

i have a Problem with silex an doctrine dbal

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE ca_mailing SET aktiviert = 2";
$count=  $app['db']->executeUpdate($update_sql, array());
echo "$count count";
```

-> 2 Records in Database, echo outs 2
-> The Records are not updated. When the db is MyISAM it works.

here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `ca_mailing` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`anrede` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`aktiviert` int(1) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1010 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution:

i had:

```
 'driverOptions' => array(
            "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
        )
```

this overwrites PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT

```
'driverOptions' => array(
            1002=>'SET NAMES utf8'
        )
```

-> this is the right way to set it